# Yii2 REST URLs not working except GET

Tags: php, yii2, yii-rest

I tried to create a **REST API** by referring [**Yii2 REST GUIDE**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/rest-quick-start.md) but unfortunately I got only GET method working.

**Example URL:**

> http://dev.exp-yii.com/employee

apart from the above URL everything else gives me a ***NOT FOUND (404)*** error page (Not even a JSON response).

**app\controllers\EmployeeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class EmployeeController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Employee';

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function verbs()
    {

        return [
            'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
            'create' => ['POST'],
            'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
            'delete' => ['DELETE'],
        ];

    }

}
```

**app\models\Employee.php**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;


class Employee extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $primaryKey = 'emp_no';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'employees';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['emp_no', 'birth_date', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'hire_date'], 'required'],
            [['emp_no'], 'integer'],
            [['birth_date', 'hire_date'], 'safe'],
            [['gender'], 'string'],
            [['first_name'], 'string', 'max' => 14],
            [['last_name'], 'string', 'max' => 16],
            [['emp_no'], 'unique'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'emp_no' => 'Emp No',
            'birth_date' => 'Birth Date',
            'first_name' => 'First Name',
            'last_name' => 'Last Name',
            'gender' => 'Gender',
            'hire_date' => 'Hire Date',
        ];
    }
```

**web.php Configuration**

```
'parsers' => [
                'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
            ]

'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'enableStrictParsing' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'employer'],
            ],
        ],
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

I hope that I have provided every relevant information to solve my problem. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam tried, no luck

Comment: why you have the `'controller'=>'employer'` when you controller name is `employee` ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, My bad it's working now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: :) you are welcome friend

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined the name of the controller as `employer` whereas it should be `employee` if i am not wrong and that is not a typo writing the code here

Change to the following

```
 ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'employee'],
```

Comment: I did not realize that because GET all was working and I don't know how. Thanks anyway

Comment: it happens with us, all the time.